# Can I live in France and pay social security in Luxembourg?

Tags: france, social-security, luxembourg

I am Luxembourgish freelancer and I'm working at home as a programmer.I'd like to go live in France (Lorraine) where accommodation is much cheaper than here.

So I am wondering:

1. Can I continue paying my social security charges in Luxembourg? (provided that I live quite close to Luxembourg so that I can use only Luxembourg's medical services)
2. If it is not possible,  which administration in France should I contact to get more information to make arrangments for the move?

Comment: What's your citizenship? If you are not from the EU, it might not even be possible (or at least quite difficult) to move to France...

Comment: @Gala the citizenship appears to be Luxembourg, as stated in the first sentence.

Comment: @Gala, yep my citizenship Luxembourgish.

Comment: @phoog & Jand I assumed it meant registered/operating in Luxembourg, could be useful to clarfiy that.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you *have to* pay contributions to the health and retirement system in the country where you work. But you are free to get healthcare in France as well, even if you work in Luxembourg and do not pay anything to the French statutory health insurance system directly. Income taxes could be more complicated.

You will find much info about this with respect to employees, and that's also the situation with which I am most familiar, but the same (EU) rules apply to self-employed people, as far as I know. See [this page from the EU commission](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/taxation/personal_tax/crossborder_workers/index_en.htm) and europa.eu pages on [cross-border commuters](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/work-abroad/cross-border-commuters/index_en.htm) and [social security cover abroad](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/unemployment-and-benefits/country-coverage/index_en.htm).

[Lesfrontaliers.lu](http://www.lesfrontaliers.lu/) might also be helpful.

Comment: Well I'm going to live in France and work from home there. So basically I'm going to be a transfrontalier. What about this?

Comment: @Jand With no commuting/presence in Luxembourg, clients' sites, etc. it's more complicated, I am not sure actually. Maybe try to look-up any bilateral tax agreement between Luxembourg and France?

Comment: There are exemptions in the EU for people on a temporary posting not exceeding five years. They can keep paying into the system of their home country even for the time they are abroad.